# How can I override env vars set dotenv via command line?

Tags: python, environment-variables, dotenv

I have the following script inside my main file, and I would like to override the value set in the `.env` file when running the script (e.g `python -e MODE=train main.py`)

main.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(os.environ["MODE"])
```

.env

```
MODE=test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage the command line arguments that your script receives

```
import os
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(os.environ["MODE"])
    param_mode = sys.argv[1]
    value_mode = param_mode.split('=')[1]
    os.environ["MODE"]=value_mode
    print(os.environ["MODE"])
```

And you call would be something like this:

```
python main.py MODE=train
```

Explanation:

*sys.argv[1]* contains *MODE=train* string, so you split by '=' to get only the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python subprocesses:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["python", " -e", "MODE=\"train main.py\""])
```